# How to style ClickableTextCell Column that was rendered as Image Column (GWT)?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I want to have an Image Column in Celltable. I don't want to use ImageResource to do that cos it got problem with the Location of Image & I can't use `setFieldUpdater`. So i used "`ClickableTextCell Column that was rendered as Image Column`" like the following:

```
     String[] msg={"12","love","image/icon/delete.jpg"}
     Column<String[], String> deleteColumn=new Column<String[], String>(new ClickableTextCell(){

            public void render(Context context, 
                    SafeHtml value, 
                    SafeHtmlBuilder sb)
             {

                sb.appendHtmlConstant("<img width=\"20\" src=\""
                                        + value.asString() + "\">");
             }

     }){

            @Override
            public String getValue(String[] object) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return object[3];
            }

     };

     deleteColumn.setCellStyleNames(getView().getRes().css().gwtCellImage());
```

in css:

```
.gwtCellImage button{

    background-image:url('/images/icon/delete.png');    
}
.gwtCellImage button:hover{

    background-image:url('/images/icon/deleteRed.png'); 
}


.gwtCellImage button, .gwtCellImage button:hover{
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

The `deleteColumn` showed Image but when I mouse over it the image did not turn to Red?

So I think i did something wrong?

Can you show me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the hint of Andrei, I came up with a solution for creating the ImageColumn in CellTable. I believed this is the simplest way to make ImageColumn:

So, don't even need to `Override render`, just create a simple ClickableTextCell & then style `background-image` for the imageColumn. It will show really nicely.

```
     String[] msg={"12","love",""}; //just put empty String value for the column 
     Column<String[], String> deleteColumn=new Column<String[], String>(new ClickableTextCell()){

            @Override
            public String getValue(String[] object) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return object[3];
            }

     };

     deleteColumn.setCellStyleNames(getView().getRes().css().gwtCellImage());
```

In CSS:

```
.gwtCellImage{
    background-image:url('/images/icon/delete.png');    
}

.gwtCellImage:hover{
    background-image:url('/images/icon/deleteRed.png'); 
} 

.gwtCellImage, .gwtCellImage:hover{
    background-size:16px 16px;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no button in your cell. Replace `button` with `img`.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrei. Your answer is not the completed one, But it is the key point that take me to a more elegant very simple way to create ImageColumn using "background-image" strategy . No question about ImageColumn on internet mentioned that technique. I hope my answer can help other people.